# AWS import vpc with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, vpc

I'm wanted to know if there is possible in Terraform to get the Default VPC ID without need to write the ID or the Name on the manifest and save it on a variable. My idea is to invoke it only knowing that is the Default VPC but not write the ID or Name, just because is the Default VPC.

Thank you

FT

Comment: of course I did it, but is not what I'm looking for.
Please take a look what I'm trying to do. You will see that I'm not trying to looking for "terraform Default VPC" as simple. It is something what I'm trying to do with terraform Default VPC. Thank you.

Comment: when you are working with aws_default_vpc or aws_vpc this expect you pass de Id at least to identify.
What I'm trying to doing is not pass de Id. Would be something like "scan" and get it by it-self without need to pass any data and save it in a variable, just because i'm logged in the aws account. My idea is te make a TF script that I can use it no matter the aws account (previously logged in)

Comment: It's clear. Look the first text, I said "without need to write the ID or the Name on the manifest and save it on a variable".

Comment: But I don't want to name it. Even the ID or the name. It is the only VPC in the account and I'm trying to get it without the need to pass the Name or ID.

Comment: cause I don't want to name it. I just want to get it because I'm logged in and is the only vpc (and the default as well) in my aws account. My goal is to get it without list the vpc on the cli or look it in the UI and put it into my tf file. Like a "scan and save in a variable what you find". I'm asking if it's possible. Again, like a said in my question at first. Thanks.

Comment: I already looked in the tf documentation and I saw the aws_vpc & aws_default_vpc but that doesn't resolve what I trying to know if it is possible to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you a reference to the default VPC in the current AWS region:

```
data "aws_vpc" "default" {
  default = true
}
```

This is documented [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/vpc).

Note that this gives you a reference to the VPC, so you can pass the ID to other resources. Terraform does not manage the VPC when you do this, it simply references it. This is different from `terraform import` which causes Terraform to start managing the VPC, and requires that you pass it the VPC ID.

Comment: Hi mark, thank you for your response. 
You know, I already try that but didn't work.
But I think didn't work because "default" refer to the VPC name. 
When you create a new AWS account for the first time, the Default VPC comes without a name. What would you do if the Default VPC hasn't name? How would you invoke it with out a Name?

Comment: It does not refer to the name. There is a "default" attribute on the VPC, and this looks for a VPC where that attribute is `true`.

Comment: Ok Mark, I already tried that way but I'm gonna try it again. Maybe I did something wrong. Thank you for your help. Very kind!

Comment: Finally works the way you mentioned.
I had to delete the tfstate file and it worked.
thank you.